# How to set TypeScriptTarget in Visual Studio 2015 RTM

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I try to build the project https://github.com/Justin-Credible/Ionic-TypeScript-MDHA-Starter but get lots of error:
    
    `error TS1056: Build: Accessors are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher.`

I editted the project file `JustinCredible.SampleApp.jsproj` by adding `TypeScriptTarget` as:
    
    `<PropertyGroup>
      <TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.5</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
      <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
      <DefaultReferenceGroup>Implicit (Apache Cordova)</DefaultReferenceGroup>
    </PropertyGroup>`

but the error was still there.

Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a **tsconfig.json** file in the **Sample-App\scripts** folder with the following content:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "out": "www/scripts/appBundle.js",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceRoot": "/"
    }
}
```

Comment: the fix was also included in the github repository.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, these property groups are read and applied sequentially.  If you move the property group further up in the project file, this will also fix the issue.